# Restricted function of space of ultrafilters of naturals to naturals

Tags: general-topology

I'm having trouble proving the following:

if $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is any function, then there exists a function $g:\beta\mathbb{N} \rightarrow  \beta\mathbb{N}$ such that $$g\restriction\mathbb{N}=f$$

---

How can I prove this using the following:

- $\beta\mathbb{N}$ is compact
- Let X be a compact hausdorff space and let $\{{X_n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of points in X, then the function $h:\beta\mathbb{N}\rightarrow X$ such that $f(U)=\lim_{n \to U}X_n $ is continuous.

Comment: You probably want $g$ to be continuous. And perhaps unique.

Answer (score 1):

For $U\in\beta\Bbb N$ let $g(U)$ be the $U$-limit of the sequence $\langle f(n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$. The results in your bullet points immediately tell you that $g$ is continuous, so you have only to prove that $g\upharpoonright\Bbb N=f$. You didn’t mention it, but you may also want to prove that $g$ is unique; this is also easy, using the fact that $\Bbb N$ is dense in $\beta\Bbb N$.